# kukushi/SideMenu navigation title not changing

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationbar, title

I am using SideMenuSwift by kukushi.

I create a SideMenuController programmitcally with following code:

```
extension DeviceScanViewController {
  static func instantiate() -> UIViewController {
    
    let homeViewController = UIStoryboard(name: "DeviceScan", bundle: nil).instantiateInitialViewController()!.embedInNavigationController()
    let menuVC = MenuViewController.instantiate()
    return SideMenuController(contentViewController: homeViewController, menuViewController: menuVC)
  }
}
```

The navigation bar title shows the name of the app like in this image ("Appname"):

[image]

I would like to change the navigation title to something else but I don't know how.

I have tried following ways:

```
  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    
    self.title = "Test123"
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.topItem?.title = "Test456"
    self.navigationItem.title = "Test789"
    
    sideMenuController?.title = "Test123"
    sideMenuController?.navigationController?.navigationBar.topItem?.title = "Test456"
    sideMenuController?.navigationItem.title = "Test789"
}
```

None of these ways work. The navigation title still shows the app name.
How can I change the navigation bar title when using SideMenuSwift?

Comment: High probability that the library uses the entire Navigation bar space, rendered for the side-menu. Meaning that using the native properties and functions will not work because it's being reset by the library itself. Check `Preferences.swift` file and see what options exist there.

Comment: @xTwisteDx I looked Preferences.swift but could not find any code related to the navigation title.

Answer (score 0):

I found out that the title of the navigation bar was being set in a function inside an extension of UIViewController called reachabilityChanged. This function was called automatically whenever the connection status of the app was updated. Therefore every time some views were loaded it would override the navigation bar title with "Appname" or "Appname (offline)". So it has nothing to do with the SideMenu by kukushi.

```
  func reachabilityChanged(_ isConnected: Bool) {
    let navBarColor: UIColor = isConnected ? .white : .offlineOrange
    let navBarTextColor: UIColor = isConnected ? .defaultPurple : .white
    
    updateViewStyle(backgroundColor: .white, navBarColor: navBarColor, navBarTextColor: navBarTextColor)
     //TODO: Localize
      title = isConnected ? "Appname".localized : "Appname (offline)".localized
  }
```

I managed to solve it by adding the following code to the view controllers and setting a tag for which I would needed to set title to "Appname" or "Appname (offline)":

```
  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    
    // Set view tag 111 so that in UIViewController extension function
    // reachabilityChanged Appname/Appname (offline) navigation title is set
    // for this view and not for Settings
    self.view.tag = 111
}
```

and for the second view controller as well:

```
  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    
    // Set view tag 112 so that in UIViewController extension function
    // reachabilityChanged Appname/Appname (offline) navigation title is set
    // for this view and not for Settings
    self.view.tag = 112

}
```

And then I changed the function reachabilityChanged to the following:

```
  func reachabilityChanged(_ isConnected: Bool) {
    let navBarColor: UIColor = isConnected ? .white : .offlineOrange
    let navBarTextColor: UIColor = isConnected ? .defaultPurple : .white
    
    updateViewStyle(backgroundColor: .white, navBarColor: navBarColor, navBarTextColor: navBarTextColor)
     //TODO: Localize
    // view tags 111 and 112 are Device Scan view and Manual Scan view
    if(self.view.tag == 111 || self.view.tag == 112){
      title = isConnected ? "Appname".localized : "Appname (offline)".localized
    }
  }
```

Now it works if I set the self.title to another text in a different view controller.